# Sharepoint and missing System.web.dynamicdata

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis-6, 64-bit

My .net application worked fine until it was moved to a sharepoint server. THe error I am getting is "Cannot find System.Web.DynamicData" .

DotNet 3.5 is  already installed on the box.

GAC (C:\Windows\Assembly) does not contain this assembly.

If I install .Net 3.5 SP1 will it disrupt anything under sharepoint (does not come under my area of responsibility). ?

What I am puzzled about is how can this server have 3.5 without these DLL/assembly - which are supposed to be part of 3.5 - does this mean the install is broken (sharepoint seems to work but not my app which depends on dynamic data).

Can I manually copy the missing DLLs ? - since its a working sharepoint server, I want to keep changes to a minimum.

Comment: Added a comment to further clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.. SharePoint works fine with .NET 3.5 SP1 installed.